# How can I prevent my QMainWindow from going past he desktop screen edges in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have a QMainWindow and some child widgets inside it.
The QMainWindow is frameless and transparent. I have kept a QPushbutton in the centre of the window for dragging the window on the screen.

When I move the window it goes past the desktop screen edges which I guess is a normal window behaviour.

I want to move my QMainWindow within the viewable desktop screen area only and not allow it to leave the desktop screen edges.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override `void QWidget::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event)`. In that handler compare the window border coordinates with the screen border coordinates and move the window back to the desired limits if screen borders are exceeded.

Be careful not to create an infinite recursion.